How to calculate the number of days until close on a summary-level formula column in a report?

To calculate number of days until Close Date. I'm getting the following syntax error 'Extra Date'

What object is the root/base of your report? "Close Date" looks like the label of a field, but what is the API Name of the field? The API Name is the one you need to use in formulas.

shouldn't this be a row level formula column?

I believe you should be using the API name of the field, which is CloseDate if the main object of your report is the opportunity.
You can read this article too, on Salesforce Ben, about Summary Formulas.

Thanks Renato, I tried it and got an error saying 'CloseDate does not exist. Check Spelling'

Try the syntax [object name].[field name], as in OPPORTUNITY.CLOSEDATE.

Thanks, but getting the same error for OPPORTUNITY.CLOSEDATE - TODAY () does not exist. Check Spelling

CLOSE_DATE:UNIQUE - TODAY () seems to be fine but says Incorrect parameter type for operator '-'. Expected Number, received Date
